# Submit form to other pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a website where the nav is search form. Basically you can only search for letters. If you search for "A" I want that submit redirects you to a.html, if you search for "B" to redirect you to b.html, and so on. Is this possible? Can I do this with css and javascript?

Comment: Of course this is possible, but is there a code sample of the things you have tried on your own? Please share your research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly I think you are just looking to get the input's value and then redirect to a url with that value.

```js
$( "button" ).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
 var letter = $('input').val().toLowerCase()
 window.location.href = "/" + letter;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input> </input>
<button> Search </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just with html form submit with GET or POST method